# copying the request header from request object to urlConnection object

Tags: java, servlets, urlconnection

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/testy/Out");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    for(Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        Object o = e.nextElement();
        String value = request.getHeader(o.toString());
        out.println(o + "--is--" + value + "<br>");
        connection.setRequestProperty((String) o, value);
    }
    connection.connect();
}
```

i wrote the above code in a servlet to post form so some alternate locations than this servlet,but its not working.is it okay to use connection.setRequestProperty to set the header fields to what they are in the incoming request to servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for

```
RequestDispatcher rd;
rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("pathToServlet");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: no actually i was trying to fetch some remote url with the headers of the current request .

Comment: Or afterwards actually not..? Else it seems wrong to set it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`URLConnection` is lazily executed. That is, it won't *actually* fire the HTTP request until you grab some information about the HTTP response. E.g.

```
int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

or

```
InputStream responseBody = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

or

```
String statusHeader = urlConnection.getHeaderField(null);
```

The `connection.connect();` is by the way entirely superfluous. It's already executed at the moment you called `url.openConnection();`. Also the `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");` is entirely superflous, the `connection.setDoOutput(true)` already does that.

That said, if the target is actually located in the same webapp context hosted at the same machine, then there are *much* better ways to invoke it than creating a HTTP connection to it, such as forwarding or redirecting the request.

Comment: Yeah it worked after  adding a line connectin.getHeaderField();

Comment: <Quote>"The connection.connect(); is by the way entirely superfluous"</Quote>
I guess connection.openConnection() lets one Manipulate parameters that affect the connection to the remote resource. 
while connection.connect() is to Interact with the resource; query header fields and contents after the connection.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: That's true, but it is still superflous in case of HTTP connections. Leave it away and you'll see that it just works.